# Profanity filter could not load Spacy model 'en'

Tags: python, spacy

I need the Spacy model 'en' for the Python profanity-filter. I would like to have a `requirements.txt` file that installs everything needed. I have the following:

```
spacy>=2.2.0<3.0.0
https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.3.1/en_core_web_sm-2.3.1.tar.gz#egg=en_core_web_sm
```

All good, but when I try to run a simple code like:

```
from profanity_filter import ProfanityFilter

pf = ProfanityFilter()

test = "This is bullshit"
test = pf.censor_word(test)
# "This is ***"
print(test)
```

I get the following error `Couldn't load Spacy model for any of languages: en`.

I think the problem is that I'm creating a symbolic link as `en_core_web_sm` while profanity-filter searches for `en`. In fact if I manually execute `python -m download en` I don't have this problem. What should I change in my `requirements.txt` in order to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't fix this in `requirements.txt`. Making the shortcut `en` work for  the model `en_core_web_sm` isn't a property of the installed package, it's something spaCy manages separately. The shortcut process relies on symbolic links and is kind of flaky, which is why it was removed in v3.

Since it looks like the profanity filter package is abandoned, your options are running [`spacy link`](https://v2.spacy.io/api/cli#link) from the command line or modifying the profanity filter package yourself.

You could also figure out what `spacy link` is doing and do that (or call the relevant functions) in code.